# Draw a line starting from a given point using `++` together with a polar coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I'd like a line starting from the red point. Why is there a gap between them? I use the following code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,rotate around={45:(2.3,5)}] (2.3,5) rectangle ++(4,0.3) ++(0,-0.15) node (p) {};
\fill[red] (p) circle (2pt);
\draw (p)--++(225:6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Either replace `node (p) {}` by `coordinate (p)` or by `node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (p) {}`, or replace `(p)` by `(p.center)` in the `\draw command`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gap is due to the default value `inner sep`  of the `\node` command for node `(p)` which is `.3333em`. Setting `inner sep=0pt` will remove the gap and reduce the node to a minimal size.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,rotate around={45:(2.3,5)}] (2.3,5) rectangle ++(4,0.3) ++(0,-0.15) node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (p) {};
\fill[red] (p) circle (2pt);
\draw (p)--++(225:6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

or

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,rotate around={45:(2.3,5)}] (2.3,5) rectangle ++(4,0.3) ++(0,-0.15) coordinate (p);
\draw (p)--++(225:6);
\fill[red] (p) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gab is caused with `˙inner sep` of node (default value is 3pt). You actualy have two possibilities:

- reduce `inner sep` of node, or
- instead node use coordinate as I suggested above

[image]